# Can’t install Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: screenshot

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on Oracle VM VirtualBox
configuration:

Base memory 2048MB
video memory 128
graphics controller: VMSVGA

but I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to start  Snap Daemon.mer
Failed to start holds snappy daemon refresh 
Failed  to start Ubuntu live CD installer
```

I downloaded the Ubuntu 22.04.1 iso

I`m sorry if I'm still not providing enough information. I'm new to this about the image the app says i can only upload a file less than 2MB

[image]

Comment: If you want to provide an image, could you please rotate it to a normal viewing angle, and with a resolution so it's actually readable? Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the VM configuration? What sort of resources have been allocated? Are you running from the ISO directly or through a Live USB that is captured by the VM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

1 - Check that virtualization (hardware) is enabled in the BIOS. Otherwise only software virtualization and 32-bit systems can run.

2 - Reduce the amount of video memory to 16mb, it's enough to use Ubuntu and if necessary, after installing it, you can increase it.

3 - Check if the amount of physical memory installed on your computer is enough to create a VM with 2048 MB of RAM. Try reducing it to 1024MB just for testing purposes.

4 - As a last resort, download the ISO again to make sure it hasn't been corrupted. If the problem persists, please download a previous version to test.

5 - Try the Xubuntu distro. It's the same base as Ubuntu, but with an XFCE graphical interface, lighter in terms of RAM consumption and suitable for machines with fewer resources.